# iOS Safari loses focus when touch/scrolling a div with overflow: auto;

Tags: html, ios, scroll, safari, overflow

I've got an issue here where I have a vertically scrolling div fill of buttons and on iOS/Safari, the focus is very unpredictable. Sometimes when you touch/scroll in the div area, the page itself scrolls. Other times it behaves as it should and scrolls the contents of the div.

I cant have the page scrolling. Any ideas? I have tried everything I can think of and no luck yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am stumped!

Here is a link that demonstrates the problem so you can try it yourself on an iOS device: https://alcatraz.fawkesengineering.com/tavis/ics-fabriceditor/touch-scroll-ios-issue.html

Heres the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <style>
        body, html {
            margin: 0; 
            color: white;
            height:1000%;
        }

        .bodyText {
            position: relative;
            left: 10px;
            top: 10px;
            font-family: "Arial", Verdana;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            overflow-wrap: normal;
        }

        .rightnav {
            background-color: #333;
            overflow: auto;
            white-space: nowrap;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;   
            width: 150px;
            height: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding-left: 50px;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        }

        .rightnav button {
            display: block;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
        }

        .container {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            border:1px solid;
        }
        .left {
            width:auto;
            height:100%;
            background:#444;
            padding: 10px;
            padding-right: 100px;;

        }
        .right {
            overflow: auto;
            height:100%;
            width:250px;
            background:#444;
            float:right;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body id='body' ontouchstart="">
        <div id="mainmenu" class="rightnav" >   

                <button >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>

                <button  >
                    scroll me
                </button>
            </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="right"> </div>
        <div class="left">
            <span class = "bodyText" >Tap here and then try to scroll on the right . <br>
                The focus is unpredictable. <br> Sometimes the contents in the div will scroll, 
                other times the page will scroll.</span>                
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: any solutions? same problem here

Answer (score 0):

Both are separate div, In DOM `div` with id mainmenu will come first then `div` with class container.

if you are clicking on somewhere `div` with id `mainmenu` or cursor/focus is there then it will scroll `div` with id `mainmenu` then `div` with class container as well.

if you are clicking on somewhere `div` with `mainmenu` or cursor/focus is there then it will scroll `div` with class `container` only.

Summary: It behaves as expected in `safari 16.2`